# How to load a inherited object with values from an instance of the inherited class?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

this is Visual Basic 2010. Thanks in advance for your attention.
I have a "customer" entity auto generated from a DataBase using EF 5.0.
I coded a new "cCustomer" class wich inherits from the mentioned class.

My idea is to give to the customer class some methods of my own while having the properties inherited from the EF class. 
The thing I really would like to do is to load a new object of my class with data from a object of the "customer" class in the most straight forward way, without expliciting each of the properties. Is this possible?

EX:

```
Public Class cCustomer
Inherits customer

Public Sub load(ByVal ID As Integer)
    Using db As New dbEntities
        Dim FoundCustomer As customer = db.cosutmers.Find(ID)

        'the next lines are the ones that I would LOVE to reduce to just one magic line. So what would be??
        me.name = FoundCustomer.name
        me.adress = FoundCustomer.adress
        me.phone = FoundCustomer.phone

    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: as long as it is not private, data in Customer (parent class) is available to cCustomer, so there is no need to move anything from Cust to cCust (if that is what `ME <---- customer (??)` means)

Comment: I made the example more clear. When somebody calls the load (id) method of my cCustomer, there is no data until customer is found using the find method of the dbSet. That is the point when I would like to load the properties of the found object onto my object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DirectCast() function on the customer object that already has data in it, as long as what you are casting it into, implements all of the original properties and methods.

```
Dim newCust = DirectCast(oldCust, cCustomer)
```

Comment: how can I do something like that but from inside the load method of my ccustomer object?

Comment: You would do this outside of this method, where you create/instantiate the actual objects